# Create li data-role=list-divider from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to create several listviews from array elements with the items in different `<li>`, something like this only then for `<li>`. Anybody can help me with that?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function() { 
    var container = jQuery('#container'); 
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) 
    { 
        var div = jQuery('<div id="div'+i+'">test</div>'); 
        div.hide(); 
        container.append(div); 
        div.fadeIn("slow"); 
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your exact code revised to build out an unordered list of elements. I hope this helps a bit!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var theList = jQuery('#yourUL'); 
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) 
    { 
        var div = jQuery('<li id="item'+i+'">test</li>'); 
        div.hide(); 
        list.append(div); 
        div.fadeIn("slow"); 
    }   
})
</script>
```

Comment: My apologies for the editing, for some reason it thinks I'm a bot so I have no wysiwyg

Comment: you might want to add the .listview('refresh') option after you append/fade to style the list with jQM css

Comment: This works fine, but now I want add a href link to the list item. I thought this is gonna work but it don't. Can you help me? var div = jQuery('<li id="item'+i+'"><a href="#add_page"><a/></li>');

Answer (score 1):

One way to create an unordered list using jQuery:

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $ul = $('<ul/>').attr('id', 'myList');

for(i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
   $ul.append('<li/>')
      .attr('id', 'li_' + i)
      .text('Some Text');
}

$ul.appendTo($container);
```